# Console game to Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have done a console game called "Labyrinth", now I want to bring it to Windows Forms, but I have some problems and exceptions and I can't understand how to make it work.

So, here is functional for printing field in console:

Base class Cell(it has children, like Wall, Door,Key,Empty, Player)

```
abstract class Cell
    {
        protected ConsoleColor foregroundColor;
        protected ConsoleColor backgroundColor;
        protected char symbol;

        public Cell(ConsoleColor foregroundColor = ConsoleColor.White,
                   ConsoleColor backgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black,
                   char symbol = ' ')
        {
            this.foregroundColor = foregroundColor;
            this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
            this.symbol = symbol;
        }

        public virtual void Draw()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = foregroundColor;
            Console.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
            Console.Write(symbol);
        }
    }
```

Here is class FileStorer that works with file(reads level from .txt file) and fills the array string[] field

```
class FileStorer
    {
        private string path;
        public string[] Result;

        public FileStorer(string path)
        {
            this.path = path;
            Result = new string[0];
            ReadFile();
        }

        private void Add(string item)
        {
            string[] newStr = new string[Result.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < Result.Length; i++)
            {
                newStr[i] = Result[i];
            }

            newStr[Result.Length] = item;
            Result = newStr;
        }

        public void ReadFile()
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Add(line);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Class Field

```
class Field
    {
        private bool toggle_key = false;
        private Cell[,] field;

        public int Width
        {
            get { return field.GetLength(1); }
        }

        public int Height
        {
            get { return field.GetLength(0); }
        }

        public Field(int width, int height)
        {
            field = new Cell[height, width];
        }

        public Cell this[int x, int y]
        {
            get { return field[y, x]; }
            set { field[y, x] = value; }
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
                {
                    this[x, y].Draw();
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        public bool NotOutOfField(int x, int y)
        {
            return x >= 0 && x < Width && y >= 0 && y < Height;
        }

        public void MakeEmpty(int x, int y)
        {
            this[x, y] = new Empty();
        }

        public bool CanMakeStep(int x, int y)
        {
            if (NotOutOfField(x, y) && this[x, y] is Empty)
                return true;
            if (NotOutOfField(x, y) && this[x, y] is Key && !toggle_key)
            {
                toggle_key = true;
                Key.count--;
                return true;
            }
            if (NotOutOfField(x, y) && this[x, y] is Door && toggle_key)
            {
                toggle_key = false;
                Door.count--;
                return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is class LevelLoader that fills array Cell[,] with proper classes (Door,Key etc.)

```
class LevelLoader
    {
        private string[] field;

        public LevelLoader(int level)
        {
            field = new FileStorer($"../../Levels/{level}.txt").Result;
        }

        public void LoadField(out Field cellField, out Player player)
        {
            cellField = new Field(field[0].Length, field.Length);
            player = new Player(0, 0);
            for (int y = 0; y < field.Length; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < field[y].Length; x++)
                {
                    switch (field[y][x])
                    {
                        case '#':
                            cellField[x, y] = new Wall();
                            break;
                        case ' ':
                            cellField[x, y] = new Empty();
                            break;
                        case 'K':
                            cellField[x, y] = new Key();
                            break;
                        case 'D':
                            cellField[x, y] = new Door();
                            break;
                        case 'P':
                            player = new Player(x, y);
                            goto case ' ';
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally in class Level I have methods that puts characters on field and prints them

```
private void PutCharactersOnField()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < gameField.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < gameField.Width; x++)
                {
                    if (!(gameField[x, y] is Wall) && !((gameField[x, y] is Key)) && !((gameField[x, y] is Door)))
                    {
                        gameField[x, y] = new Empty();
                    }
                }
            }
            gameField[player.X, player.Y] = player;
        }
```

```
public void PrintLevel()
        {
            gameField.Print();
            player.Draw();
            LivesMessage();
            if (Door.count == 0)
            {
                Win();
            };
        }
```

I have done some changes for winforms, and I got IndexOutOfRanfeExceprion, I can't understand what went wrong, so here are the same classes and functions but changed for Winforms.

Class Cell

```
public abstract class Cell
    {
        public string Path;
        public Image Image;

        public Cell(string path)
        {
            Path = path;
            if (!File.Exists(Path))
            {
                throw new  Exception("File does not exist: " + Path);
            }                
            Image = new Bitmap(Path);
        }

        public virtual void Draw(Graphics gr, int j, int i, int side, int x, int y)
        {
            gr.DrawImage(this.Image, j * side + x, i * side + y, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(side, side)), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }
```

FileStorer wasn't modified.

Class Player

```
public class Player:Cell
    {
        public string path;
        protected Direction direction;      
        public Image SpriteAnimation;
        public int X, Y;
        public Size Scale;
        public int CurrentFrame = 2;
        public int CurrentAnimation = 5;
        public Image Part;
        public int speed;

        public Direction CurrentDirection
        {
            get { return direction; }
        }

        public Player() : base("D:\\GIT\\maze-game\\MazeGame\\MazeGame\\Resources\\sprite.png") { }

        public Player(Size scale, int x, int y, Image spriteAnimation):base("D:\\GIT\\maze-game\\MazeGame\\MazeGame\\Resources\\sprite.png")
        {
            SpriteAnimation = spriteAnimation;
            Scale = scale;
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            speed = 2;
            if (!File.Exists(Path))
            {
                throw new Exception("File does not exist: " + Path);
            }
            base.Image = new Bitmap(Path);
        }

        public Player(int x, int y) : base("D:\\GIT\\maze-game\\MazeGame\\MazeGame\\Resources\\sprite.png")
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public void Action()
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case Direction.Left:
                    CurrentAnimation = 1;
                    break;
                case Direction.Up:
                    CurrentAnimation = 3;
                    break;
                case Direction.Right:
                    CurrentAnimation = 0;
                    break;
                case Direction.Down:
                    CurrentAnimation = 2;
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void Static()
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case Direction.Left:
                    CurrentAnimation = 6;
                    break;
                case Direction.Up:
                    CurrentAnimation = 8;
                    break;
                case Direction.Right:
                    CurrentAnimation = 5;
                    break;
                case Direction.Down:
                    CurrentAnimation = 7;
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void Rotate(int dx, int dy)
        {
            if (dx == -speed)
                direction = Direction.Left;
            else if (dx == speed)
                direction = Direction.Right;
            else if (dy == -speed)
                direction = Direction.Up;
            else if (dy == speed)
                direction = Direction.Down;
        }

        public void MakeStep(int dx, int dy)
        {
            X += dx;
            Y += dy;
        }

        public void DrawAction(Graphics gr, int x, int y)
        {
            gr.DrawImage(SpriteAnimation, X + x, Y + y, new Rectangle(new Point(75 * CurrentFrame, 170 * CurrentAnimation), new Size(75, 170)), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        public void DrawStatic(Graphics gr, int x, int y)
        {
            gr.DrawImage(SpriteAnimation, X + x, Y + y, new Rectangle(new Point(75 * CurrentFrame, 170 * (CurrentAnimation - 5)), new Size(75, 170)), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
}
```

Class LevelLoader was modified juct for player cell

```
case 'P':
   player = new Player(new Size(35, 75), 100, 100,player.Image);
   goto case ' ';
```

Class Field

```
class Field
    {
        private bool toggle_key = false;
        private readonly Cell[,] field;

        public int Width
        {
            get { return field.GetLength(1); }
        }

        public int Height
        {
            get { return field.GetLength(0); }
        }

        public Field(int width, int height)
        {
            field = new Cell[height, width];
        }

        public Cell this[int x, int y]
        {
            get { return field[y, x]; }
            set { field[y, x] = value; }
        }

        public void Print(Graphics gr, int side, int j, int i)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
                {
                    this[x, y].Draw(gr, x, y,side, j, i);
                }
            }
        }

        public bool NotOutOfField(int x, int y)
        {
            return x >= 0 && x < Width && y >= 0 && y < Height;
        }

        public void MakeEmpty(int x, int y)
        {
            this[x, y] = new Empty();
        }

        public bool CanMakeStep(int x, int y)
        {
            if (NotOutOfField(x, y) && this[x, y] is Empty)
                return true;
            if (NotOutOfField(x, y) && this[x, y] is Key && !toggle_key)
            {
                toggle_key = true;
                Key.count--;
                return true;
            }
            if (NotOutOfField(x, y) && this[x, y] is Door && toggle_key)
            {
                toggle_key = false;
                Door.count--;
                return true;

            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Here are Level class method PrintLevel,(PutCharactersOnField wasn't modified)

```
public void PrintLevel(Graphics gr)
        {
            gameField.Print(gr, mapSide,point.X, point.Y);
            player.DrawStatic(gr, point.X,point.Y);
            if (Door.count == 0)
            {
                Win();
            };
        }
```

I'm very new in this topic, but I want to deal with this issue.So, I need help, what is wrong, where I made a mistake?

**Exception was called in the [stack of calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac1Yb.png)

Comment: I which class / line do you get the IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: Class Field Line 24 public Cell this[int x, int y]
        {
            get { return field[y, x]; }
            **set { field[y, x] = value; }**
        }

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Here, it would also really help to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If the game has been designed to be a console app I personally wouldn't port it to WinForms as it doesn't really make sense.